# Slackware 14.2 - Turn on the auditd daemon

Tags: services, daemon, slackware, start-stop-daemon

I want to turn on / enable the `auditd` daemon to record system events in Slackware 14.2. I could not see the daemon `auditd`, when I run the code below:

```
ls /etc/rc*.d | grep "auditd"
```

It means it was not existing. How will I enable auditd in Slackware? I know how to start, stop and restart services but if it is not existing , how will I make that service up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution does not provide `auditd`, but one can find the build script [SlackBuild](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/system/audit/). (The URLs will change in the future.) Create a working directory and acquire the required files.

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/audit && cd /usr/local/src/audit
wget http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/audit-2.3.6.tar.gz
wget https://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.2/system/audit.tar.gz
```

Unpack the Build script, and move the source code into the Build directory.

```
tar xf audit.tar.gz && rm audit.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/src/audit/audit
mv /usr/local/src/audit/audit-2.3.6.tar.gz /usr/local/src/audit/audit/
```

It's important to read notes associated with the Build.

```
less README
less README.SLACKWARE
```

Execute the Build script.

```
/usr/local/src/audit/audit/audit.SlackBuild
```

After the software has been compiled successfully, the script installs all of the binaries, libraries, and configuration files required for the software to execute inside of a package file. Use `installpkg`.

```
installpkg /tmp/audit-2.3.6-x86_64_SBo.tgz
```

Optionally remove the source, temporary, and package files.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/src/audit/ /tmp/SBo/ /tmp/audit*
```

The audit subsystem is not enabled in Slackware kernels, so one must also rebuild the kernel with support for the audit subsystem in order to use `auditd` as intended.